# Magento adding products locally and migrating it to production

Tags: magento-1.9, product, git

I have setup a `test` Magento environment locally and i push the changes to `production` using a `git repository`. However when i add products using the production admin dashboard the product images doesn't get added to the repo as i'm **not committing changes from production environment**. What are the best practices to do `admin panel` changes when you have several magento environments? And also if i add the **products** locally what is the best practice to migrate the product info from the local database to production?

Comment: A product is a database entry. You should create an installer script to set it up, which will then run wherever you deploy your module

Comment: I think your solution is viable if a person is adding 1 or 2 products. If i'm suppose to add a lot of products how to achieve?

Comment: @Lakshin, why not just add products on the production site and keep them disabled until they're ready?

Comment: @musicliftsme the problem when adding products on the production site is the images of the products are getting saved in the media directory and it doesn't sync up with my repo because it's not a good practice to push changes to the repo from the production server.